# Converting url encoded string(utf-8) to string in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, python-2.x

I have a url encoded token(utf-8)= `"EC%2d2EC7"` and I want to convert it to `"EC-2EC7"` i.e convert `%2d` to `-`.

```
>>> token = "EC%2d2EC7"
>>> token.encode("utf-8")
'EC%2d2EC7'
```

I also tried `urllib.quote` but same result. Is the problem that token is already in `utf-8` so it can't convert? What can I do?
My python version: 2.7.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**`urllib.unquote`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote):

```
from urllib import unquote

print unquote("EC%2d2EC7")
```

Another way is to use **`requests.utils.unquote`**:

```
from requests.utils import unquote

print unquote("EC%2d2EC7")
```

Output:

```
EC-2EC7
```

Comment: This is it, thanks. What's the difference between unquote and quote ?

Comment: quote replaces special characters using the %xx escape, unquote changes it back

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `unquote` instead of decode.

```
urllib.unquote('EC%2d2EC7')
```